# Hot Reloading issue about developing react native On Windows Envioment

Tags: android, windows, facebook, react-native

Everyone.
I'm developing React Native lately.
I've successfully created a android app sample as installation guide:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
but the Hot Reloading function is not working for me...
so it's not really convenient to develop something.
I don't have mac to test React Native and my development environment is based on Windows 7,
 android studio(Android SDK, JDK1.8), HTC one(Android 5.0.2)
Is it the reason react-native start server not firing when index.android.js file changed?
or some plugin I should add in the project? like webpack or watchman..
thanks!

Comment: Could you tell me the version of nodejs and react-native?

Comment: nodeJS:v4.4.5, react-native:0.28.0

Comment: Install latest node version then It works right now, thanks man!

Comment: The version 4 of nodejs has this issue. Nodejs 5 and 6 work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest NodeJS Long Term Support release (6.10.x) should fix this issue.