# Hot reloading does not update changes

Tags: react-native, hot-reload

I have a react native app, right now when I make changes to it hot-reloading is triggered but the changes do not show up in the app. E.g. changing a background color from green to white in a stylesheet causes app to say "Hot Reloading" but then the color stays white. Fully reloading the app will then show the green background.

Things I have tried:

[Setting root component to a class.](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/88)

[Removing yarn.lock](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10889)

[Reinstalling watchman](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10889)

[Trying to set MAX_WAIT_TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726377/react-native-hot-reloading-refreshes-but-not-updating-the-changes) (did not work due to solution being outdated)

[Installing Babel Functional HMR](https://github.com/bvic23/babel-plugin-functional-hmr)

Running simulator via Xcode and `react-native run-ios`.

Running with only hot-reload, both hot-reload and live-reload, only live-reload. With and without remote-debugging.

System:
MacOS: 10.13.2
React-Native: 0.51.0
React-Native-Cli: 2.0.1
Xcode (for running the simulator): 9.2

What is going wrong here? How can I get hot-reloading to work?

**EDIT:**

Looks like this is an [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16505). Keeping this question open incase someone has a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to react-native 0.48.4 solved the problem. Still not an optimal solution, so I won't mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**_#    ###SOLUTION**

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

OUTPUT will be :
c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser>react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
Scanning folders for symlinks in c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser\node_modules (43ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser\node_modules (38ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output

and after

Run react-native run-android again, you will find your modification work.

Thanks to : 
[https://lengerrong.blogspot.am/2018/01/react-native-run-android-do-not.html][1]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && npm uninstall watchman && npm install watchman
```

or

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman
```

Then

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: what are your arguments for posting that answer ?